# CSS all that start with chaining - CSS select all IDs that start with "u" and are in :hover and control other id that start with u

Tags: css, css-selectors

I hope I'll be able to explain.

I've got automatically generated code that I wish to override with CSS.

Here is an example of the code I wish to override:

```
#u1150:hover #u1153-4 p {color: red}
```

IMPORTANT: "u" in this code will always be generated, other numbers will be randomly generated and added to u (e.g. #u3726 or #u3427-12). Since I can always count on u being generated, I want to grab control over those IDs via the u letter and change the color so I tried this:

```
[id^u]:hover [id^u] p {color: green !important}
```

In plain language I tried to:
1. Select all IDs that start with u and are in :hover
2. further select all IDs that start with u
3. further select p tag and give it different color (in this case green)

Can this be achieved because my code isn't achieving the desired result.

Comment: `[id^="u"]` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Keep in mind that the actual id selector has a higher specificity than the attribute selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `=` symbol after the `^`.

```css
[id^="u"]:hover [id^="u"] p { ... }
```

```css
[id^="u"]:hover [id^="u"] p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="u123">
  <span id="u124">
    <p>Hover here to make this green</p>
  </span>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="u245">
  <div>
    <div id="u246">
      <p>Hover here to make this...</p>
      <span>
        <p>...and this green</p>
      </span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```